# Eigenvalues from pandas rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` with rows representing a symmetric matrix component.

```
                            sxx         syy             szz         sxy         syz         sxz                                                                                           
    NodeID      time
    1500000     20921.0     2504729.0   -16524560.0     -3966213.0  5058878.0   8026349.0   390275.7
                20923.0     2541577.0   -16459500.0     -3930280.0  5047995.0   8019404.0   393201.3
                20925.0     2582004.0   -16384690.0     -3891037.0  5035703.0   8011226.0   396850.2
                20927.0     2618859.0   -16313310.0     -3855520.0  5024095.0   8003384.0   400578.7
                20933.0     2703961.0   -16133460.0     -3773937.0  4995101.0   7985394.0   411183.2
```

The matrix will look like the following.

```
[[sxx, sxy, sxz],
 [sxy, syy, syz],
 [sxz, syz, szz]]
```

What is the fastest way to calculate the eigenvalue from each row?

I tried 'applying' `np.linalg.eigvalsh` on every row. However, it takes quite long when I have close to a million lines.

**Edit**

To give the complete context, I should also mention that this `DataFrame` is part of an object definition. `object.df` is the `DataFrame`. Below is the related code.

```py
    def s1(self):
        """Returns the first principal stress for every node every timepoint"""
        return self.df.apply(principal, axis=1, label="s1")

def principal(s, label):
    principals = np.linalg.eigvalsh(
        np.array(
            [s.sxx, s.sxy, s.sxz, s.sxy, s.syy, s.syz, s.sxz, s.syz, s.szz]
        ).reshape(3, 3)
    )
    if label.lower() == "s3":
        return principals[0]
    elif label.lower() == "s2":
        return principals[1]
    elif label.lower() == "s1":
        return principals[2]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid Input, choose from s1, s2, or s3.")
```

Comment: How are you applying it to each row? Post the code? Are you reshaping the rows into symmetrical square matrices first?

Comment: Actually this dataframe is part of an object definition. I'll post related info as part of the question.

Comment: @DrBwts, yes. Each row in the dataframe is actually the upper part of a symmetric matrix.

Comment: you could do away with the `.reshape(3,3)` and deifine the matrix as `np.array([[s.sxx, s.sxy, s.sxz], [s.sxy, s.syy, s.syz], [s.sxz, s.syz, s.szz]])` to start with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the order of the columns to generate a view and then pass it to an array using `.values` (faster than `np.array(..)`), then apply `eigvalsh` to an `(n, 3, 3)` array:

```
values = df[['sxx', 'sxy', 'sxz', 'sxy', 'syy', 'syz', 'sxz', 'syz', 'szz']].values.reshape(-1,3))
eigh = eigvalsh(values.reshape((-1, 3, 3)))
eigh

>>array([[-21253030.07083309,  -1397298.11167328,   4664284.18250638],
       [-21184732.23304478,  -1361435.36228467,   4697964.59532944],
       [-21106512.77176102,  -1322433.70013306,   4735223.47189408],
       [-21032246.72681734,  -1287171.41922922,   4769447.14604654],
       [-20847979.70886149,  -1205613.19093403,   4850156.89979552]])
```

Comment: This is a much faster method! However, I loose the index data. I think I can re-create the `pd.Series` from the numpy array by using the same index as the dataframe.

Comment: Exactly. You should end with an array with the first dimension being the same length as your dataframe, and in the same order. You don't have an index in the array, but you can always access the original dataframe using `iloc`, or simply append the columns back